# JAXB/MOXy - afterUnmarshal() appears to be called inconsistently

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink

I'm having trouble where the `afterUnmarshal()` methods on my classes are not called if the class is a member of a collection.

Beyond declaring the method on a class which is created via unmarshalling, is there any other steps I'm required to perform?  (I can't see anything else in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback))

Here's a test which shows the problem I'm having:

Given these two domain classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Parent")
public class Parent {

    public boolean unmarshalCalled = false;

    @XmlPath("Children/Child")
    List<Child> children;

    void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent)
    {
        unmarshalCalled = true;
    }
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Child {

    public boolean unmarshalCalled = false;

    @Getter @Setter
    @XmlPath("@name")
    private String name;

    void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent)
    {
        unmarshalCalled = true;
    }
}
```

This test fails:

```
public class UnmarshalTest {

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void testUnmarshal()
    {
        String xml = "<Parent><Children><Child name='Jack' /><Child name='Jill' /></Children></Parent>";
        JAXBContext context = getContext();
        Parent parent = (Parent) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
        assertTrue(parent.unmarshalCalled);
        for (Child child : parent.children)
        {
            assertThat(child.getName(),notNullValue());
            assertTrue(child.unmarshalCalled); // This assertion fails
        }
    }
    @SneakyThrows
    public static JAXBContext getContext()
    {
        JAXBContext context;
        context = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class);
        return context;
    }
}
```

Is this a bug, or have I missed some steps to get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is due to the following EclipseLink MOXy bug:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/364410

This bug has already been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.3.3 stream, a nightly download can be obtained from:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

**Workaround**

You can workaround the issue that you are seeing by ensuring that all of the classes with event methods are included in the array of classes passed in to create the JAXBContext.   I have modified you code below to do this:

```
@SneakyThrows
public static JAXBContext getContext()
{
    JAXBContext context;
    context = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class, Child.class);
    return context;
}
```